# Reset timeout in vuetify snackbar

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuex

I am looking for a solution to reset snackbar timeout in vuetify.

For example I open snackbar when I have response from api while logging in:

```
        if (data.status == "success") {
          this.$router.push({ name: "dashboard" });

          this.$store.commit("snackbar/open", {
            color: "success",
            text: data.message
          });
        } else {
          this.$store.commit("snackbar/open", {
            color: "error",
            text: data.message
          });

          this.apiErrors = data.errors;
        }
```

My point is that I first log in with an error -snackbar is displayed, then I quickly change data to correct and color of snackbar and the message change, but the visibility time does not count again, it is based on the old one.
How can I do this so that time is reset every time the snackbar is opened? I mean, if snackbar is visible and I open another one, time will count again.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main class="grey lighten-3">
      <router-view></router-view>
      <Snackbar />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
  import Snackbar from "./components/Snackbar";

  export default {
    name: "App",

    components: {
      Snackbar
    }
  };
</script>
```

snackbar.module.js

```
const state = {
    visible: false,
    color: "success",
    text: "",
    timeout: 4000
}

const mutations = {
    open(state, payload) {
        state.text = payload.text;
        if (payload.color) { state.color = payload.color; }
        if (payload.timeout) { state.timeout = payload.timeout; }
        state.visible = true;
    },

    close(state) {
        state.visible = false;
        state.text = "";
    }
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    mutations
}
```